diffie hellman key exchange compared with ECDH
I have to write a paper about the Diffie Hellman key agreement. I want to focus on the implementation with elliptic curves and comparing the safety for selected attacks such as Pollards Rho and Pohling-Hellman.
Does anyone know some papers where I can find this information?

That sounds interesting and you will learn a lot! I assume you are a student.
You should start at the start: "New Directions in Cryptography" - This is a fundamental and well-written paper. Let's say, this is where it all began :D
In general, the Diffie-Hellman key exchange is fundamental in cryptography. The Wikipedia article about it is quite good and includes a lot of good sources. Look at the References; they should help you.
I can also suggest the Wikipedia article for elliptic curve cryptography. If you are searching for a concrete construction to implement, I would suggest Curve25519. It is fast; the paper is well-written, and all parameters are explained. However, the paper is pretty technical; reading it takes some time (at least for me).
Regarding Pollard Rho, there is a section in the book Introduction to Algorithms. If you are a computer science student, this may be easier to understand than more mathematical descriptions. But the Wikipedia Article is also great.
Elliptic and Hyperelliptic curves are quite similar, especially regarding the attacks. I can recommend the book on Hyperelliptic Curves. Both attacks should be well described in this book. I recommend only reading the sections you need; otherwise, the book may be a bit overwhelming.

Thank you very much!
